# Changing the default page for a custom site type in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I want to change the default page for a site of a custom type that I've defined, I know that the default page in defined in the `slingshot.site.configuration.xml` but it changes the default page to all sites, is there any way to customize this for my needs ?

Answer (score 4):

Default layout site is defined here
**presets.xml**

Under

```
<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-data\presets
```

So now if you want to change this out of box layout you can create your own preset file and keep it under extension

```
<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\site-data\presets
```

If you are using AMP then it will go with AMP file at given location.

Comment: It's worth noting that the presets.xml file only defines the Surf objects (Pages and Components) that will be created when creating a new type. It's something of a "cookie-cutter" approach, so updating a preset will not have any impact on sites previously created from that preset. However, as mitpatoliya says, the presets file is the correct place to define new site pages.